# How to prove by contradiction that there is only one circle with the given segment AB as its diameter?

Tags: geometry

I am very very weak in proving by contradiction as I don't know how to start or choose the assumption.

> Let $AB$ be an arbitrary line segment. Prove that there is only one circle
>   with $AB$ as its diameter.

Comment: Let there be two circles with the same diameter $AB$ . Both of them have the same radius . Two circles with same radius are same and hence our original assumption contradicts and we have only one circle .

Comment: The answer you edited in seems reasonable. But it would be better to post that as an answer, not as an edit to your question. Unless you have reason to still doubt that approach, which you should make clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My effort is as follows. Please help me to spot the false argumentation.

### Assumption

Assume that there are 3 circles $C_1$, $C_2$, and $C_3$ passing through the points $A$ and $B$. $C_1$ and $C_2$ are concentric and $C_1$ and $C_3$ are not concentric. $C_1$ and $C_2$ have different radii and $C_3$ has any radius. Let $C_1$ be on the midpoint of $AB$ such that $AB$ is its diameter.

### Contradicting Arguments

- As $C_1$ and $C_2$  have different radii, points $A$ and $B$ cannot be on the circle $C_2$.
- As $C_3$ is not on the middle of $AB$, $AB$ cannot be its diameter.

### Summary

So there is only one circle $C_1$ with $AB$ as its diameter.